# how to shut down cherrypy server?

Tags: python, cherrypy

im on win7 ,i started a tutorial helloworld.py and everything doing fine but i don't know how to quit the service.i use

```
quit()
```

but command line give me an error message and exit.but service is still running and take my 8080 port. i hadn't find a way to shut down it manually.

```
  File "C:\python32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\wspbus.py", line 197, in
publish
    output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\python32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpserver.py", line 151, in start

    ServerAdapter.start(self)
  File "C:\python32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\servers.py", line 167, in
 start
    wait_for_free_port(*self.bind_addr)
  File "C:\python32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\process\servers.py", line 410, in
 wait_for_free_port
    raise IOError("Port %r not free on %r" % (port, host))
IOError: Port 8080 not free on '0.0.0.0'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this page](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#quit), `quit()` is not appropriate for this task.

Depending on how you run your server, you should consider using [`cherrypy.engine.exit`](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/process/wspbus.html#cherrypy.process.wspbus.Bus.exit):

```
>>> help(cherrypy.engine.exit)
exit(self) method of cherrypy.process.win32.Win32Bus instance
    Stop all services and prepare to exit the process.
```

Answer (score 8):

Include this in your python file.

```
@cherrypy.expose

def shutdown(self):  
    cherrypy.engine.exit()
```

Then add a link on your page.

```
<a id="shutdown"; href="./shutdown">Shutdown Server</a>
```